# How do I start the appium desktop 1.6.1 in mac using .bat

Tags: java, testing, automated-tests, appium-ios, appium-android

I am building a framework from scratch and I want to start appium desktop automatically as part of the testing process. I know I can use a .bat file to run appium  server to perform this task.

My question is:

1. Is this also possible in appium desktop?
2. If it is possible, how do I do that step by step?
3. If it is not possible what can we do or use instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can start appium server directly from your code where you can mention other supported parameters such as logs, port no etc. Below is an example of AppiumServiceBuilder class

AppiumServiceBuilder serviceBuilder = new AppiumServiceBuilder().usingAnyFreePort();
service=AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(serviceBuilder);
service.start();

Comment: I am curious about the above syntax.  Excuse my ignorance, do I need to add anything to this syntax to get to invoke appium desktop or is it complete?  (ie. port number etc). I've never built a framework before, so I would rather ask the 'dumb question' than not 'ask the dumb' question. Does that make sense?

Comment: the above Questions is for @S Bera

Comment: You can create a startServer() method and put these statements.

Comment: AppiumServiceBuilder serviceBuilder = new AppiumServiceBuilder().usingPort(4723).withLogFile(); This will start appium on 4723 port and in case you need logs you can add .withLogFile(filepath)